# How to get mysql node in node-red?

Tags: mysql, node-red

I've tried `npm install node-red-node-mysql` and it ran successfully, but when I start node-red, no node like mysql can be found. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in your Node-RED user directory - typically ~/.node-red

> npm install node-red-node-mysql

Also

> The reconnect retry timeout in milliseconds can be changed by adding a line to settings.js

mysqlReconnectTime: 30000,

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I didn't run the command in the node-red directory.